# serve with apache all paths under a domain through one script

Tags: apache, url, path

i'm hosting a website through a hosting company [1] on a linux/apache server. until now i serve the different content through one script with parameters. an example url is

```
www.mydomain.com/pages.php?date=1-10-2008
```

now i want to change the scheme the url is composed of to something which looks completely like a path url. eg.:

```
www.mydomain.com/pages/date/2008/20/1
```

for this i need to *switch off the normal mapping* of url paths to directory folders in apache: all requests to all paths should go to one central script (pages.php), which than analyzes the path component of the url.

how do i tweak apache for this? i hope some .htaccess rules could the trick.

[1] btw, the hosting company is [godaddy.com](http://www.godaddy.com/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . pages.php
```

should rewrite every request for a file or directory that doesn't exist to pages.php. This will allow you to keep static files (images, stylesheets, etc) in the same document root.

(Shamelessly stolen from WordPress :) )

Comment: I should read the docs before checking the community wiki box :(

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html). Example htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^pages/([^/]*)/(.*)$ pages.php?$1=$2
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than parse the url in your script, you should be able to handle the specific example above with Apache's ModRewrite module.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html

You can use these in the .htaccess file, assuming your host allows this.