# Is this PHP code dangerous?

Tags: php, security

I've just sketched up the main index.php file. It should be the gateway for all the site requests. The reason why I want that is to have clean URLs.

I have split my website into modules. (Example: register, articles etc..)

Then I've included some lines in .htaccess, one is this:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)[/]?([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)[/]?([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)[/]?([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)[/]?([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)[/]?([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)[/]?([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)[/]?([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)[/]?([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)[/]?$ index.php?1=$1&2=$2&3=$3&4=$4&5=$5&6=$6&7=$7&8=$8&9=$9 [L,NC]
```

This just maps each "folder" to the right $_GET element... domain/1/hi/3

```
$_GET['2'] == 'hi'; // TRUE
```

So I want to run the module based on the first $_GET element. This way I can keep my project organized. And all files associated with a module is inside its folder.

Here is my folder structure:

```
/
    modules/
        register/
            ajax/
                process.php
            register.php
        articles/
            articles.php
    index.php
```

And here is the PHP-code to map everything (index.php):

```
<?php

$basePath = 'modules';

for ($x = 1; $x <= 9; $x++) {
    if (preg_match('/[^a-zA-Z0-9-]/', $_GET[$x])) {
        require_once(__DIR__ . "/$basePath/404/404.php");
        die();
    }
}

$baseModule = $_GET['1'];

if (file_exists(__DIR__ . "/$basePath/$baseModule/$baseModule.php")) {
    require_once(__DIR__ . "/$basePath/$baseModule/$baseModule.php");
} else {
    require_once(__DIR__ . "/$basePath/404/404.php");
}
```

Is this dangerous code? The reason why I do the regex is to check that the GETs doesn't contain . or / which could be used to do ../ and thus run virtually any file on the server...

Does this still pose a security hole, a potential security hole, or is it in fact, bad practice?

What is the best approach to this problem?

Comment: Why would you let anyone choose the filename - instead of making this choice by yourself (depending on params)?

Comment: @raina77ow Are you suggesting using a switch with predefined calls depending on the input?

Comment: Exactly, if there are few files to use. Alternatively, you can extract some part of request (and this part will _always_ follow the rules you set) and `require` depending on it.

Comment: @raina77ow If so, the reason why I didn't do that, is that I'm concerned about speed. I think I'll have approximately 200 modules in the end, and I thought using a switch with that many options would be slow to execute with every single page request. I'm NOT experienced when it comes to factors that affect the speed, so please correct me if I'm wrong here.

Comment: BTW, why do you filter all $_GET variables when you deal only with the first one?

Comment: Wouldn't it be cleaner to do this directly in Apache rather than in PHP?

Comment: @raina77ow Because I'm going to use the other ones as well later on. I just set that up so that if I forget it later on, it's more secure than if I hadn't done it..

Comment: @raina77ow Though I'm probably not going to forget about the index.php file it's just a practice I use.

Comment: @AllInOne Maybe it would. But the main reason why I do it in PHP is that I've heard that Apache rewrites are very slow. Besides, there is no validation in Apache.. But if you you think your solution is better than the one I've come up with, please add an answer explaining it more! :)

Comment: Can you post some more examples of what a 'clean URL' is?  And what the significance of each URL segment is?

Comment: @AllInOne Okay. I want for example to do http://www.domain.com/article/article-name and http://www.domain.com/admin/article/new

Comment: What happens when the value is many many characters long? Does this somehow behave in some unexpected manor? Does it depend on the specific operating system/version? Does it depend on the filesystem in use by the os?

Comment: @AllInOne One of the modules is a HUGE module that has many sub-modules. And so there will be a lot of different parameters. That's why I thought using a predefined list of parameters would be too slow. But the solution I came up with seems a bit dodgy. Because there is no "white-list". Only a "black-list". So I've thought of using ../ as a hack, but what if I've overlooked something. It could be fatal.

Comment: @rambocoder I didn't catch that entirely. But I'll give it a try. Many characters will not be a problem, I think. Or was this a rhetorical question? It should work on my development platform Windows and my deployment platform Linux (Ubuntu or Debian). It shouldn't depend on the filesystem. That's why I use "relative" paths. (As far as \_\_DIR\_\_ goes..)

Comment: Instead of mapping to query parameters in apache, [why not just redirect everything to your index.php page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/551965/serve-with-apache-all-paths-under-a-domain-through-one-script)? And then parse `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI]` in PHP however you see fit.

Comment: @gschwa I'm going to try mapping the parameters in PHP like you suggested. On my localhost (WAMP-server) the Apache rewrite line takes on average 250 ms to execute!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me yes - read about **include injections**. In combination with other parts, for example insecure file uploads this could even "kill". See [here](http://rgaucher.info/post/2006/10/27/How-to-scan-for-basic-php-include-injection).

```
__DIR__ . "/$basePath/$baseModule/$baseModule.php"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^/article/(.*)$ http://example.com/articles/articles.php
```

Then in article.php you look at the url segments and handle as you see fit.

@gschwa's approach would work well too.

Comment: Yes, but then I'm back to where I started. I have one module that has a lot of sub-modules. About 170 of them actually...

Comment: Do you know how the speed impact will be if I define each and every module manually in Apache?

Comment: Do you pay a price for Apache rewrites? Yes, but this is what Apache is made to do. I suspect it will be faster to do it in Apache than to do what is essentially the same thing in PHP.

Comment: So you think it's not going to be slow if I have 200 modules?

Answer (score 0):

I figured that defining all the options in an array is the best alternative, because it did NOT have a speed impact on my code when validating it with in_array(). The code was insecure because it COULD allow attacks. I have not found any method that would be able to penetrate the security, but I think it was still a bit on the edge this one.

The reason why I think this is the best alternative, is that Apache is slow.

Please vote this answer up or down, and I will accept the answer with the most votes. (I don't get any reputation if I accept this answer anyway.)