# jQuery convert URL to parameters across entire site

Tags: jquery, urlencode

Let's say I have a directory web site and want to display details for every city in the US. I want the link mysite.com/CA/fairfield to go to a specialized page on the city Fairfield, CA, which is dynamic.

I know I can read the URL parameters using window.location.pathname.split("/"). What I'm not getting is how I set up a single script that monitors any combination of URL parameters on my site. I don't mean how to actually get the string "CA", but conceptually, how do I force someone typing in CA/fairfield to go to a certain script so I can check what they entered?

Comment: Are you using jquery only? Or do you have access to a server side language (php, .NET etc)? You will need to setup a function on page load that checks the URL parameters then performs actions based on.

Comment: I have access to PHP and MYSQL. Don't think I can run .NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of thing is generally determined by the server. For example if you are using apache to serve your files and you have a directory structure

```
-web_root
   -CA
      -fairfield
         index.html
   index.html
```

your request to mysite.com/CA/fairfield would fetch the index.html file in the fairfield folder on your server.

If however you want one script for all your towns but still want separate urls then try something like [serve with apache all paths under a domain through one script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/551965/serve-with-apache-all-paths-under-a-domain-through-one-script)

Comment: Thanks. It looks like I can do this with .htaccess and mod_rewrite.